# Wait for some time in between onMouseDown() function in unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I have built this 2D project in unity where you tap on blocks and they destroy using the onMouseDown() function. My problem is after tapping a block and it destroys, how can I make the player wait for a certain amount of time before he can tap on another block in the game. I have tried using PlayerPrefs and subtracting Time.deltaTime from a certain float variable but it did not work.

Note: all the blocks share the same destroy script!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
float waitTime = 1.5f;
static float lastClickTime = float.NegativeInfinity;

void OnMouseDown ()
{
    float time = Time.time;
    if( time > ( lastClickTime + waitTime ) )
    {
        lastClickTime = time;
        DestroyThisBlock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If they all share the same script, you can start with defining a static bool variable and a static event, say:

```
public static bool isLockedDown = false;
public static event Action onBlockDestroyed;
```

Then, on destruction function, first keep a check about this locked down. If this is false, then destroy, turn the lock to true, and invoke the static listener that'll be read by another script, which in turn will start a coroutine that'll turn this static lock to false after given set of seconds.

```
public class Block : MonoBehaviour {

    void DestroyBlock()
    {
        if(isLockedDown)
            return;

        isLockedDown = true;
        onBlockDestroyed.Invoke();
        ////destroy block///
    }
}

public classBlockManager : MonoBehaviour {
    void Awake()
    {
        Block.onBlockDestroyed += BeginUnlocking
    }

    void BeginUnlocking()
    {
        StartCoroutine(UnlockTimer);
    }

    IEnumerator UnlockTimer()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        BLock.isLockedDown = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried using the script you gave on the game right now but it only works on the block you clicked on first  and the other blocks don't destroy when clicked on. Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh hey, sorry my bad, it skipped me that if you destroy the object, the coroutine will be destroyed too, and won't work ahead. I've edited the code in my answer.

Comment: Glad it helped!